# C# - Is it possible to read the pixels from an image without using the Bitmap class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, bitmap

I am trying to read the pixels from a jpeg image in a C# console application using Bitmap. I keep getting this error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.

That implies that it can not be done on a Mac (which I am using). Is there any way to get the pixels from a jpeg image without using Bitmap so that I don't get this error? Here is my code:

```cs
Bitmap bp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path);
string line = "";
for (int y = 0; y < bp.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bp.Width; x++)
    {
        var col = bp.GetPixel(x, y);
        if (col.R < 20 && col.B < 20 && col.G < 20)
        {
            line += 'B';
        }
        else
        {
            line += 'W';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try out [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: you need to know the image data format and read the file as arbitrary bytes as dictated by that format.

Comment: @RichardBarker or, you know, use a cross-platform library

Comment: If you really need the `Bitmap` class, you can install [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common) from NuGet.